# iframe mixed content warning without mixed content

Tags: javascript, iframe, https, mixed-content

Maybe I'm just losing my mind here, but I keep getting mixed content warnings for this page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        </head>

        <body>
           <iframe scrolling="no" id="slides" src="admin/slides.html"></iframe>
           <iframe scrolling="no" id="sidebar" src="/sidebar"></iframe>
           <iframe scrolling="no" id="ticker" src="/clock2"></iframe>
        </body>
    </html>
```

It's confusing me greatly, since everything is on the same domain, and all pages are served over https. To add to the confusion, the first iframe actually works without a warning, the second two don't. Also, the second two pages work just fine over https when you go to them directly. They don't even exist on http - my .htaccess redirects to https. All the resources are loaded over https. I've even tried using the fqdn with the https prefix in the src instead of a relative reference, but it doesn't help.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why it happends, but the redirect from /sidebar to /sidebar/(index.html) is going over HTTP. I'm pretty sure replacing the links with /sidebar/index.html or just /sidebar/ would resolve your issue.

I just tested it, here's a screenshot of the links /sidebar/ and /clock2/ loading over https. http://puu.sh/nzsnu/b421dfb4bd.png

Comment: Well that's weird, but you sure are right. That's got to be a setting on the server somewhere. I'll have to see what I can track down.

Comment: Glad to see it worked, if you find out what caused the http redirects, do you mind posting it here?

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a similar issue and was super confused, because both resouces were https. As soon as I completed the url with /index.html the issue was gone.